# Error with Autofac in Xamarin Android App

Tags: xamarin.android, autofac

I am using Autofac in a Xamarin project to build a Mobile App. I get the following error when building an Autofac container, in Xamarin Live Player 1.5.176 (676) (on a Huawei P20, last security patch) :

> [LogEntry: Time=01/07/2018 11:00:08 +02:00, Level=Error,
>   Title=Visualization Error, Message=No body on method
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration>
>   Autofac.Core.IRegistrationSource::RegistrationsFor(Autofac.Core.Service,System.Func`2>)
>   (NInterpretException)]

I made a solution to reproduce the issue : https://github.com/EhRom/XamarinAutofac/

```
// Initialiaze container builder.
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder.RegisterType<SampleViewModel>().As<ISampleViewModel>();

// Build container.
container = containerBuilder.Build();
```

The error occurs on the Build() method. I tried to add options, with no success.

Have you ever encountered this problem ? How can I solve this ?

The error is not reproduced on the local emulator (without Xamarin Live Player).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from Xamarin Live Player.

I deployed the apk directly on my phone and works fine.